# Regex is grabbing preceding character

Tags: regex, f#

So I am experiencing some inconsistent behavior in my regex

My regex:

```
(?<=test\\\\)(.*)(?=\",)
```

The input string:

```
"test.exe /c echo teststring > \\\\.\\test\\teststring",
```

When I run this in https://Regex101.com

I get the value `teststring` however when I run this in F#

```
Regex.Match(inputString, "(?<=test\\\\)(.*)(?=\",)")
```

I get `\teststring` back. My goal is to get just `teststring`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: btw. your regex is just too complicated, you also can just use `test\\\\(.*)\",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had success using triple quoted strings. Then only the regex escapes need be considered, and not the F# string escapes.

```
let inputString = """test.exe /c echo teststring > \\\\.\\test\\teststring","""
let x = Regex.Match(inputString, """(?<=test\\\\)(.*)(?=\",)""")
```

"teststring" comes out

The string in your source comes out as

```
(?<=test\\)(.*)(?=",)
```

If you don't want to use triple quotes or verbatim, you will have to write this in F# :

```
"(?<=test\\\\\\\\)(.*)(?=\\\",)"
```

This string in F# uses backslashes to escape backslashes and a quote character. There are eight backslashes in a row in one place, and this then becomes four actual backslashes in the string value. There is also this:

```
\\\"
```

which translates to one actual \ and one actual " in the actual string value.

So then we end up with a string value of

```
(?<=test\\\\)(.*)(?=\",)
```

This then is the actual string value fed to the regex engine. The regex engine, like the F# compiler, also uses the backslash to escape characters. That's why any actual backslash had to be doubled and then doubled again.

Comment: We actually came to this same solution. My next question is... Why would matching 4 backslashes to 2 backslashes inside a string literal make sense or work for that matter lol

Comment: @AnthonyRussell - In short: because it's important to be able to put backslashes in a string literal. And the most natural way to express a backslash is as an escaped character like any other, so `\\` in the string literal becomes `\` in the actual string. All the rest follows naturally from that decision: four backslashes in a string literal are really *two occurrences* of a `\\` pair, meaning *two occurrences* of a real `\` in the string. And so on.

Comment: @rmunn I get what it's doing I just think it's silly. The entire point of the string literal is to not have to worry about escaping things lol

Comment: That's why the `@` syntax exists, to turn off backslash escapes: `@"\n"` is two characters, a backslash and a lowercase n. But the default is to allow backslash escapes, because you want to be able to write characters like `\u1234` in your strings. You may not like the defaults, but they're the defaults for good reason -- because *most of the time*, backslash escaping is what you want, and you can turn it off pretty simply with the `@` syntax when you're doing regular expressions.