# Escaping Asterisk Grabs wrong character

Tags: regex, f#

When I run the code below I get the unexpected result where `\*` also captures `É`. Is there a way to make it only capture `*` like I wanted?

```
let s =
    "* A

ÉR

* B"
let result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "\n(?!\*)", "", Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)
printfn "%s" result
```

**Result After Running Replace**

```
* AÉR
* B
```

**Expected Result**

```
"* A

ÉR
* B"
```

**UPDATE**

This seems to be working, when I use a pattern like so `\n(?=\*)`. I guess I needed a `positive lookahead`.

Comment: I don't know F#, but I'll bet you need to escape the backslash so it gets passed literally to the Regex function.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. But in F# a string is like @"" in C#. Actually, I finally figured out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, not an update to the question.

Comment: @Barmar I'll do that once Stackoverflow let's me. There is a waiting period after you ask a question. :-(

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting negatives on this one. I used an answer I found elsewhere on Stackoverflow but apparently it didn't work properly. So, this is a great answer for others that are looking for the same information.

Comment: Some people (not me) voted to close because they found the question unclear. That may also be why someone downvoted it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141685/discussion-between-jon49-and-barmar).

Comment: @Jon49 - "in F# a string is like `@""` in C#" -- not actually true. I just verified this in F# Interactive: `"\t"` is a string containing a single tab character. `@"\t"` is a string containing two characters, a backslash followed by a lowercase t. `"\t".Length` is 1, and `@"\t".Length` is 2. So in F#, just like in C#, you need to specify the `@` if you want to have backslashes counted as literal backslashes. (Or use triple-quoted strings: `"""\t""".Length` is also 2).

Comment: We recently answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262175

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you need to use positive lookahead instead of negative lookahead to get the result you want.  However, to clarify an issue that came up in the comments, in F# a string delimited by just `""` is not quite like either a plain C# string delimited by `""` or a C# string delimited by `@""` - if you want the latter you should also use `@""` in F#.  The difference is that in a normal F# string, backslashes will be treated as escape sequences *only* when used in front of a valid character to escape (see the table towards the top of [Strings (F#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/strings)).  Otherwise, it is treated as a literal backslash character.  So, since `'*'` is not a valid character to escape, you luckily see the behavior you expected (in C#, by contrast, this would be a syntax error because it's an unrecognized escape).  I would recommend that you not rely on this and should use a verbatim `@""` string instead.

In other words, in F# the following three strings are all equivalent:

```
let s1 = "\n\*"
let s2 = "\n\\*"
let s3 = @"
\*"
```

I think that the C# design is more sensible because it prevents confusion on what exactly is being escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I learned something new! Yes, it looks like it is confusing in F#.